# Generate end-entity certificate with OpenSSL for localhost on IIS

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl, self-signed-certificate, iis-10

I would like to ask how to generate end entity certificate based on my own CA root certificate? 
I've generated root CA this way:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -days 3650 -nodes \
    -keyout example.key -out example.crt -subj /CN=MyCompany \
    -addext subjectAltName=IP:192.168.100.82

openssl pkcs12 -export -out cert.pfx -inkey example.key -in example.crt
```

I have imported cer file to *Windows Trusted Root Certification Authorities* and pfx file into *IIS Server Certificates*.

It works well with Chrome, IE and Edge, but Firefox reports a problem with my cert: **MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_CA_CERT_USED_AS_END_ENTITY**

I googled it and I learnt that I should have end-entity cert signed by my CA root cert. I was trying to generate end-entity cert with:

```
openssl genrsa -out server.key 4096
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr -subj /CN=MyCompanyEE -addext subjectAltName=IP:192.168.100.82
openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA cert.pem -CAkey example.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -days 3650 -sha256
openssl pkcs12 -export -out server.pfx -inkey server.key -in server.crt
```

OpenSSL response:

```
Signature ok
subject=CN = MyCompanyEE
Getting CA Private Key
```

I have imported server.pfx into *IIS Server Certificates* too, and changed bindings for my web app to use server cert, but now it doesn't work in either Firefox or Chrome.

Firefox says: **SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN**,

Chrome says: **NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID**.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your problem is that you incorrectly generate your CA certificate with OpenSSL. Very first line. You have to include `isCA=true` bit in `Basic Constraints` extension in CA certificate. And OpenSSL on Windows? Consider to use `New-SelfSignedCertificate` PowerShell cmdlet. It allows to create self-siged CA certificate and CA-signed end entity certificate.

Comment: I thought that isCA is inherited from `openssl.cnf` file (`basicConstraints = critical,CA:true`). Is adding `-addext basicConstraints=critical,CA:true` for CA root cert and `-addext basicConstraints=critical,CA:false` for end-entity cert will be ok?

Comment: Give it a try. When creating CA cert, ensure that Basic Constraints is presented and `cA` bit is set to 1.

Comment: In my root CA cert in _Details_ tab I have `Basic Constraints` field with `Subject Type = UC` and `Path Length Constraint = None`, but for end-entity cert there is no field like `Basic Constraints` in _Details_ tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to generate certificate with OpenSSL for local website (available in intranet at 192.168.100.82:997) so - according to @Crypt32 advice - I changed approach and I've used PowerShell. You can find my working solution below:

1. Run PowerShell **as administartor**.
2. Use below code for generating selfsigned root authority (MyCompany CA) and server (MyCompany) certificates:

   ```
   $authorityCert = New-SelfSignedCertificate `
   -Subject "CN=MyCompany CA,OU=IT,O=MyCompany Certificate Authority,C=US" `
   -KeyAlgorithm RSA `
   -KeyLength 4096 `
   -KeyUsage CertSign, CRLSign, DigitalSignature, KeyEncipherment, DataEncipherment `
   -KeyExportPolicy Exportable `
   -NotBefore (Get-Date) `
   -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(10) `
   -HashAlgorithm SHA256 `
   -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\LocalMachine\My" `
   -FriendlyName "MyCompany CA" `
   -TextExtension @("2.5.29.37={text}1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1", "2.5.29.19={critical}{text}ca=1")

   $devCert = New-SelfSignedCertificate `
   -Subject "CN=MyCompany,OU=App Test,O=MyCompany,C=US" `
   -KeyAlgorithm RSA `
   -KeyLength 4096 `
   -KeyUsage DigitalSignature, KeyEncipherment, DataEncipherment `
   -KeyExportPolicy Exportable `
   -NotBefore (Get-Date) `
   -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(10) `
   -HashAlgorithm SHA256 `
   -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\LocalMachine\My" `
   -FriendlyName "MyCompany" `
   -TextExtension @("2.5.29.37={text}1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1", "2.5.29.17={text}IPAddress=192.168.100.82") `
   -Signer $authorityCert

   $directory = "C:\Users\bug_2\Certificates\"
   if(!(test-path $directory))
   {
     New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $directory
   }
   $authorityCertPath = 'Cert:\LocalMachine\My\' + ($authorityCert.ThumbPrint)
   $authorityCertFilename = $directory + "Authority.cer"
   Export-Certificate -Cert $authorityCertPath -FilePath $authorityCertFilename
   $devCertPath = 'Cert:\LocalMachine\My\' + ($devCert.ThumbPrint)
   $devCertFilename = $directory + "Dev.cer"
   Export-Certificate -Cert $devCertPath -FilePath $devCertFilename
   ```
3. Add root certificate to Trusted Root Certification Authorities in your system by press WIN+R, type: *mmc*, hit ENTER. In *Microsoft Management Console* choose `File->Add or Remove Snap-ins` and then, in new window, `Certificates -> Add -> OK`.
   Expand `Certificates->Trusted Root Certification Authorities`. Right click on *Certificates* catalog placed inside *Trusted Root Certification Authorities* and choose `All Tasks->Import...` and select `Authority.cer` file from `C:\Users\bug_2\Certificates\`. Apply changes and close *Microsoft Management Console*.
4. You can finds your new certificates (root and server) in IIS without any extra steps. Choose your website in IIS, click `Bindings...->Edit` and select server certificate (MyCompany). Apply changes.
5. My website is available now at `https://192.168.100.82:997` on every web browsers (like Chrome, IE, Edge) except Firefox. For fix that run Firefox, type `about:config` in address bar and set `security.enterprise_roots.enabled` to true. **Restart Firefox**.

Now my localwebsite is available in intranet at https://192.168.100.82:997.